# <hr> tag with 'OR' in the middle

Tags: html, css

This code works fine in Firefox and Chrome. Problem is with IE and Opera - 'OR' visible only in area of 2px height.

```
hr {
  height: 2px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #444;
}

hr:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #111;
}

hr:after {
  content: 'OR';
  color:#ccc;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#222;
  width:60px;
  margin:-10px auto 0 auto;
}
```

backgroung #222222

in HTML just `<hr>`

Any suggestions now to make it work in IE and Opera?

Thanks

---UPDATE---[SOLVED]---------------------------------------------

need to add position:absolute; left:50%; & transform: translate(-50%);

```
hr {
    height:2px;
    border:0;
    background-color: #444;
    line-height:20px;
}

hr:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #111;
}

hr:after {
    content: 'OR';
    color:#ccc;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#222;
    width:60px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%);  
}
```

Thanks

Comment: add to `hr`, `line-height:20px;`

Comment: Thanks. Got working code with you help

Comment: Another option is to use `border-top` instead of `background` and `height` to create thin horizontal line. See the 8th example on [Chris Coyer's demo page](http://css-tricks.com/examples/hrs/) for reference.

Comment: Ilya, yah its pretty shorter. Thanks

Comment: Instead of "Update: Solved", could you please move your solution to be an answer?  This way, it becomes more useful to the community.

Comment: Thanks Jake. I have not needed reputaion level to answer my question at past moment. will do

Answer (score 0):

need to add position:absolute; left:50%; & transform: translate(-50%);

```
hr {
    height:2px;
    border:0;
    background-color: #444;
    line-height:20px;
}

hr:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #111;
}

hr:after {
    content: 'OR';
    color:#ccc;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#222;
    width:60px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%);  
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I understand your example, but you doing the wrong way. Their is another way for using text in the middle. remove `<hr>` tag and replace it with this example:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>MY FORM</legend>
      Name: <input type="text"><br>
      Email: <input type="text"><br>
      Date of birth: <input type="text">
     </fieldset>  
</form>
```

there is `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` tags are used to show the text in the middle of the line

Comment: This does solve the problem but HTML tags should *never* be used purely for presentation purposes.

Comment: fieldset and its daughter tag legend have very specific semantics. They act as a grouping mechanism for input fields, implying that they are related in some manner (like First Name, Last Name, and MI; or credentials block) and separated to some extent from other fields/groups on the page. MrMisterMan is correct in asserting that using them because they happen to, in your version of your browser on your OS, be presented a certain way is dodgy, and annoying to people using screen readers (which was their original target audience, FYI).

Comment: In my case I'm not need to use fieldset/legen as just need to have only hr tag.